# CentOS7 issue with NetworkManager - interface configured as static (manual) but interacts with DHCP

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, networkmanager

I have an issue with NetworkManager on CentOS7( I know, but i have to use it, because of *REASONS* :( ).

I have a network interface of a VM configured with static IP. which worked for some time now. 
Last week I performed a reboot and when back up the server was with different IP.

Found in /var/log/messages that NetworkManager actually did interact with the dhcp server:

```
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname dhclient[18720]: DHCPREQUEST on ens160 to *.*.*.* port 67 (xid=0x7ce97e61)
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname dhclient[18720]: DHCPACK from *.*.*.* (xid=0x7ce97e61)
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6372] dhcp4 (ens160):   address TheNewIPaddress
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160):   gateway *.*.*.*
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160):   lease time 86400
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160):   nameserver '*.*.*.*'
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160):   nameserver '*.*.*.*'
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160):   domain name 'domain.name'
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1583434542.6377] dhcp4 (ens160): state changed bound -> bound
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [ens160]: new request (3 scripts)
Mar  5 19:55:42 hostname nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [ens160]: start running ordered scripts...
```

I don't know why since it is configured as

```
ipv4.method:                            manual
```

and

```
nmcli c s ens160 | grep -i dhcp
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:  

               --
```

Here are the contents of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME=ens160
UUID=someuuid
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=TheNewIpFromDHCP
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=mygateway
DNS1=mydns1
DNS2=mydnhs2
ZONE=public
```

Now for the sake of testing I have rebooted a second time and the address didn't change this time.

Do you guys have any idea what may be causing this? I just need it to stay static with the IP that I provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the ifcfg file is not really relevant. What matters is how the profile gets interpreted by NetworkManager when loading the file. And that you see less ambiguous with `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE_NAME"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the profile that you look at is activated?

If you set `ipv4.method=manual`, then it seems rather unlikely that NetworkManager would do DHCP with that profile.

See all your profiles with `nmcli connection` and look at what is currently activated with `nmcli device`.

Other than that, look at the logs, what it says aside the part that you pasted. Enable verbose logging by setting `level=TRACE`.